# How to handle save on Lightning Record Page using LWC?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, rerender, refresh, lightning-record-page

I am working on a Lightning Web Component that is placed on record page and retrieves data for the record. The component visualizes two links, represented by **lightning-formatted-text**. Both links use a couple of field values from the record in their urls as parameters. This is already built and working. The problem comes when I update any record field without refreshing the page. Links keep using the old values, or if blank - keep showing the old errors.

I wonder how can I handle the native **save** and somehow rerender the page or just invoke the functions, which I made responsible for setting the values in my urls? Data for the record is pulled on client-side, so I do not want to use `refreshApex`. Already saw that `getRecordNotifyChange`, which looks like exactly what I need, but I am trying to find a way to fire it only when the record is updated.

Comment: add your code to know where exactly have to use `getRecordNotifyChange`  service

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use a `@wire` method like described in [this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_example)

Basically the `getRecord` in a `@wire` will be trigger any time the record change in the Lightning Data Service (LDS). Standard use the LDS to update record, and you can too using `updateRecord` method.